# During the Beta stage - can the rep for editing be lowered?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, beta, editing

On [StackOverflow.com](http://www.StackOverflow.com) I have enough rep to edit post, clean up text, fix typos, add links etc. etc.

With these beta sites, the small things don't get cleaned up because no one has enough rep yet.

Is there any chance that the rep can be lowered for the beta period?... or that I might be able to "borrow" rep from another account "in trust" that I lose should I use my powers for evil vs. good?

Comment: This should probably be asked on meta.stackoverflow.com. See [this post by Robert](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-this-meta-site-going-to-get-merged-with-meta-stackoverflow-com-at-some-point/13#13).

Comment: I think similar questions have been asked on meta.SO but for the main site. I totally agree that on SO, the rep level needs to be high to stop trolls, however on this beta (and similar betas) I think there is a risk that the existing question/answer base will not get cleaned up at all, since users (even trusted elsewhere users) need 2,000 rep to fix a typo.